# Extraer parte de una url según patrón

Tags: r, stringr

Tengo una lista de urls como esta, y me gustaría extraer el número que hay despues de **id**. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

https://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/team/_/id/91/bellarmine-knights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que una forma bien simple, siempre que el formato se mantenga, es dividir la cadena por cada `/` y el octavo elemento debería ser el valor esperado:

```
url <- 'https://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/team/_/id/91/bellarmine-knights'

strsplit(url, '/')[[1]][8]
[1] "91"
```

Algo más preciso podría ser usar expresiones regulares:

```
url <- 'https://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/team/_/id/91/bellarmine-knights'
patron <- ".*/id/([0-9]+)/.*"
gsub(patron, "\\1", regmatches(url, gregexpr(patron, url)))
[1] "91"
```

En este caso, usamos el patrón `".*/id/([[0-9]+)/.*"`, que básicamente captura los números entre las cadenas `*/id/` y `/*`

O bien, con `stringr` puedes probar con `str_match()` que en realidad te retornará una matriz, que puede ser incluso más cómodo para trabajar:

```
patron <- ".*/id/([0-9]+)/.*"
stringr::str_match(url, patron)

     [,1]                                                                           [,2]
[1,] "https://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/team/_/id/91/bellarmine-knights" "91"
```

Comment: Como siempre gracias Patricio

Answer (score -1):

no haz especificado ninguna preferencia y los tags que elegiste no sé si se refieren al lenguaje de programación `R` o fue un error de dedo. No sabemos si la url SIEMPRE será de espn o de urls similares. Tampoco sabemos si espn SIEMPRE usa las urls de esta manera. Por lo tanto no puedo dar respuestas concretas. Ver mis protips al final.

Sea el lenguaje que sea, la opción más clara , aunque tal ves poco eficiente, sería la siguiente

1. Encuentra `/id/` y parte el string
2. Usa la 2nda parte y "corta" hasta el primer `/`
3. Usa el id

ejemplo en javascript

```
let url = "https://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/team/_/id/91/bellarmine-knights"
let id = url.split('/id/')[1].split('/')[0];
```

Esto depende de que la url siempre sea "igual". Es decir que siempre tendrá el mismo formato.

Portips para mejorar tus preguntas en el futuro:

- Cuando se trata de encontrar patrones, da más ejemplos.
- Da ejemplos de resultados ideales.
- Provee ejemplos de lo que ya haz intentado